# Can I use GTM and GA4 tracking codes together?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Can I use GTM and GA4 tracking codes together into the website code?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about droping the scripts for both GTM and GA4 within your pages, yes. You can do this but it isn't ideal.

If you are planning on using GTM, you only need to drop the container snippet code into your pages(head and body scripts). To deploy GA4, you would leverage the Google Tag within GTM.